# Need to save the value in a text box

Tags: javascript, html, loops, ms-access

I am fetching data from an Access database using a JavaScript `while` loop:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script>
function fnadd()
{
    var a=[];
    var con=new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
    var rs=new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
    con.open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= C:test.mdb;Persist Security Info=False");
    rs.open("select * from test",con,1,3);

    var n=rs.RecordCount;

    while(!rs.eof)
    {
        document.write(rs(1).value);
        rs.MoveNext();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Name: <input type="text" id="textbox_1">
<input type="button" value="view" onclick="fnadd();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to save this data in a text box?

Comment: Inside the loop you can try  tb.value = tb.value + " " + rs(1).value

Comment: @PSK will it display all the value in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example shows how to list rows. If you want to add a value to database you can use ADODB commands like this:

```
function fnadd()
{
    var con=new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
    var rs=new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
    con.open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= C:test.mdb;Persist Security Info=False");

    var textbox = document.getElementById("textbox_1");
    var commandText = "INSERT INTO test values ('" + textbox.value + "')";

    var result = con.execute(commandText);
    //check result here
    con.close();
}
```

I assumed your table has 1 column. Change sql command according your table structure.

Comment: Now it will save value of textbox to database.

Comment: Sorry you misunderstand my question my query is will the text box display all the values in the database

Comment: Sorry you misunderstand my question my query is will the text box display all the values in the database

Answer (score 0):

If this is your actual code then I must say that

> It is very bad idea to use connection strings in javascript

Still if you want to show all values from 1 `column` in an `input` box as `csv`, use `string concatination`

```
<script>
function fnadd()
{
    var a=[];
    var con=new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
    var rs=new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
    con.open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= C:test.mdb;Persist Security Info=False");
    rs.open("select * from test",con,1,3);

    var n=rs.RecordCount;
    var myStr = "";
    while(!rs.eof)
    {
        //document.write(rs(1).value);
        myStr =myStr+rs(1).value+ ", ";
        rs.MoveNext();
    }
    //You have to remove last comma from string though before assigning to input box 
    document.getElementById("textbox_1").value = myStr;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why it is bad connection vai JavaScript

Comment: Somehow, javascript is renderef on browsers and open for attacks. Also notice that your connection string path is missing separator / after c: